# How to pass request parameters to Jitterbit Web Service Method?

Tags: jitterbit

I am new to Jitterbit.

Can any one tell me how to pass request parameters to Web Service ?

I have a function called

```
updateCandidate($string, $string, $mulitDarray, $array) {

..

}
```

I have set up this in WSDL and added WSDL in websevice method and selected this function as Operation.

What is next ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new operation of type Web Service Call. Navigation: View > Design > Right click on Operation and Create a new operation
   [image: To Create a new operation]
2. Create a new web service method and upload a new WSDL to the server.
3. Use the request and response structures of the WSDL and map it to the input variables.
   You need to use a script before the transformation to load the variable values and can use those variables in the transformations.